# Customize detailed issue view in JIRA

Tags: jira

I have searched through options and FAQ but did not find an answer: I want to customize the **detailed issues view** screen to display, on the left part (the issues list) the Component(s) and the assignee icon if possible:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Details View* of the *Search Issues* screen, you cannot choose which columns to display in the list of issues (at least not yet with JIRA 6.x or 7.x).

If you switch to the *List View* instead:
[image]

Then you can use the Columns control to choose the info you want to see. You won't get to see all of the issue details for the selected issue though.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was fearing :)